# Dictionary code just loops over and over again

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I have a text file I am designing for a mock store I named 'Bodn's Superstore'.

 I designed a .txt database as such.

```
iPhone
28273139
5.50
Book
81413852
1.50
Charger
62863152
3.00
Plug
25537398
4.50
```

You can see it follows the format

```
Name
Code
Price
```

The code I have written is intended to conver the database to a dictionary, and the customer can choose the quantity of products they buy. They then enter the 8 digit code into the computer and the IDLE works to figure out the name of the product.

The code is displayed below. It first validates the code to ensure it is 8 characters long. (Python 3.4.2)

```
database = open("SODatabase.txt", "r")
list = {}
for line in database:
    key = line.strip()
    code = next(database).strip()
    price = next(database).strip()
    # next(database).strip() # if using python 3.x
    list[key]=code,price

numberItems=int(input('State the quantity required. >> '))
with open('SODatabase.txt','r') as searchfile:
    for line in searchfile:
        while True:
                userCode=input('What product would you like? Enter the product code >> ')
                try:
                    if len(str(userCode))!=8:
                        raise ValueError()
                    userCode=int(userCode)
                except ValueError:
                    print('The code must be 8 characters long.')
                else:
                    for key, value in list.items():
                        if userCode==value:
                            print (key)
```

Now, the validation of the code works.
Say for example, I want to buy 1 iPhone.
This is what appears in the main window.

```
State the quantity required. >> 1
What product would you like? Enter the product code >> 2827313
The code must be 8 characters long.
What product would you like? Enter the product code >> 28273139
What product would you like? Enter the product code >> 28273139
What product would you like? Enter the product code >>
```

And so on and so forth.
The code simply won't work backwards to find the key of the dictionary and print it, which is "iPhone".
I want to receive the name "iPhone" after I've stated my quantity and the product code, but my Python File won't work back through the dictionary to find the key that corresponds to the product code (value) I have given it.

Comment: You should probably avoid using the name `list` since it will mask the builtin, and especially so if you're not actually using it to store a list ;)

Comment: You have a never ending `while True:` statement in your code, you loop over each line but you'll stay stuck on the first loop iteration in your `for line in searchfile`

Comment: Also, `value` will be a tuple, so will never test equal to the string you want

Comment: @Paradoxis could you please explain your comment as an answer! I would grately appreciate it! :)

Comment: There's a number of things flawed in the design, but the main reason that you're never getting the key printed, is mentioned by Eric Renouf: you're comparing the userCode to one of the values of the dictionary, which in your case are tuples. You could solve it with `userCode==int(value[0])`. Debugging is a useful skill to have, make sure to check the values of your variables when something odd happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why `for line in searchfile` is required; seems like a copy mistake.

Anyway, `userCode` never equals `value` because `value` is a tuple; it can however equal `value[0]`, where you saved the codes.

How about that?

```
while True:
    userCode = input('What product would you like? Enter the product code >> ')
    try:
        if len(str(userCode))!=8:
            raise ValueError()
        userCode = int(userCode)
    except ValueError:
        print('The code must be 8 characters long.')
    else:
        for key, value in list.items():
            if userCode == value[0]:
                print (key)
```

Comment: When I add the code `28273139` it loops back to the same question again `What product would you like? Enter the product code >>` after I've entered the quantity.

Comment: That's because the comparison of `userCode` (an integer) to `value[0]` will always fail: `value[0]` is a string in the original code. Cast it to an int when you're making the dictionary or use `int(value[0])` in the comparison.

Comment: `next(database).strip()` => `int(next(database).strip())`

Answer (score 1):

```
database = open("SODatabase.txt", "r")
list = {}
for line in database:
    key = line.strip()
    code = int(next(database).strip())
    price = next(database).strip()
    # next(database).strip() # if using python 3.x
    list[key] = code, price

while True:
    userCode = input('What product would you like? Enter the product code >> ')
    if userCode == "":
        break
    try:
        if len(str(userCode)) != 8:
            raise ValueError()
        userCode = int(userCode)
    except ValueError:
        print('The code must be 8 characters long.')
    else:
        for key, value in list.items():
            if userCode == value[0]:  # code is stored as 1st element of value
                print (key)
```

Couple of things to note:

1. Please refrain from using 'list' as variable name.
2. There is no need to open the database file again.
3. While storing the details, you are storing them as a tuple containing (code, price). So, to compare the userCode, you should be comparing it with the first element of the tuple and not the whole tuple.
4. The code just loops over and over again because there was no exit statement to exit the loop.